# Googletest: Duplicate symbols linker error

Tags: c++, googletest

I have tests for my classes `ArithmeticSvc` and `BigNumber`. Both header files have their respective header guards. My tests for `ArithmeticSvc` throw a duplicate symbol error when including `BigNumber` in its header file. The relevant files are below:

`BigNumber.h`

```
#ifndef BIG_NUMBER_H
#define BIG_NUMBER_H

#include <string>
#include "stack.h"
using namespace std;

class BigNumber {
    bool isNegative;
    string num = "0";
    public:
        BigNumber(string num);
        BigNumber(string num, bool isNeg);
        string getNum();
};

#endif
```

`ArithmeticSvc.h`

```
#ifndef ARITHMETIC_SVC_H
#define ARITHMETIC_SVC_H

#include "bignumber.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ArithmeticSvc {
    public:
        ArithmeticSvc();
        string evaluate(string exp);
};

#endif
```

`bignumber_test.cc`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "bignumber.h"

namespace {
    TEST(BigNumber, ShouldPass) {
        ASSERT_FALSE(false);
    }
}

#endif
```

`arithmeticsvc_test.cc`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "arithmeticsvc.h"

namespace {
    TEST(ArithmeticSvc, ShouldPass) {
        ASSERT_TRUE(true);
    }
}
```

Error log snippit:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN9BigNumber6isZeroEv in:
    /var/folders/m2/cd4zt6556h992_b0g27h1s8c0000gn/T/arithmeticsvc_test-3a62e1.o
    /var/folders/m2/cd4zt6556h992_b0g27h1s8c0000gn/T/bignumber_test-b9cad9.o
duplicate symbol __ZN9BigNumber6getNumEv in:
    /var/folders/m2/cd4zt6556h992_b0g27h1s8c0000gn/T/arithmeticsvc_test-3a62e1.o
```

I use this command to compile tests:

`g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lgtest -lpthread *.cc -o main_test`

Does anyone know how I can test a class with dependencies that also have their own tests in google test?

Comment: Essential information missing is your build commands and build log. Please add to your post.

Comment: Neither of the duplicate symbols (demangled = `BigNumber::isZero()` and `BigNumber::getNum()`) is
defined in the posted code, and only the latter is declared in class `class BigNumber`
as posted. The code being compiled and linked is more than we see and differs from
what we see. [mcve] needed.

Comment: Why are you linking all your tests into a single binary?  Just create one test program from each source file.